# Is there a way to get a line which intersects 3 spheres?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, intersection

I am trying to find a way to get a line (point from my current view), which intersects 3 spheres. They are close together and might not intersect every time.
I also thought it would be possible to imagine it as circles and a overlapping part.

Comment: There may be none, one, two,... or infinite solutions. You may add some conditions to reduce the sumber of solutions.

Comment: A good place to ask this question would be in StackOverflows' math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why not find the intersection between the 3 spheres and then, if such intersection does contemplate all spheres, find any line crossing it ? If such intersection doesn't exist, no line can cross all spheres at the same time from your point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is definitely a way. You can formulate this problem as three quadratic inequalities. I am going to assume the origin of your coordinate system is the point of view. If not, you have to perform a change from whatever coordinate system the configuration is represented in to the coordinate system of your point of view. You have the coordinates of the centers `P1, P2, P3` of the spheres and their corresponding radii `r1, r2, r3`. You are looking for a vector aligned with a line passing through the point of view (the coordinate system's origin) and intersecting all three spheres. You can think you have a screen at a distance `h` (`h` can be simply set to 1), parallel to two of the coordinate axes of your pint of view coordinate system. E.g. the screen is parallel to the x,y plane so you can represent the vector as `V = [V_x, V_y, h]`. Then, the line determined by `V` intersects the three spheres exactly when the following quadratic inequalities for `V` hold:

```
(r1**2 - dot(P1,P1)) * dot(V,V) + (dot(P1,V))**2 > 0 
(r2**2 - dot(P2,P2)) * dot(V,V) + (dot(P2,V))**2 > 0 
(r3**2 - dot(P3,P3)) * dot(V,V) + (dot(P3,V))**2 > 0
```

In what follows, I am suggesting a geometric approach, that allows you to find a solution to the inequalities above. However, since there are various special (call them degenerate) cases, one has to go over the different scenarios, which are enough to make one not wanting to write this down completely. I will just write an algorithm for the  general (non-degenerate) case. I will assume that the closest sphere to the origin is completely visible, while the other two spheres have both visible and invisible parts (and that there is an overlap of the three spheres from your point of view, i.e. there is a solution to the inequalities).

The idea is that given two spheres and a point of view, such that one sphere, the more distant one, have both visible and invisible parts, then there exist exactly two lines through the point of view that are tangent to both spheres. So, in your case of three spheres S1, S2, S3, for any pair of spheres Si and Sj, find the unit vector Vk that is aligned with the tangent line of the spheres Si and Sj, such that the said tangent line also intersects the third sphere Sk. So, if you project your three spheres onto a screen, looking from the point of view, the three unit vectors V1, V2, V3 point to the three vertices of the common intersection of the projections of the spheres (which is a convex set because it is the intersection of convex sets, i.e. ellipses). Hence, the centroid of the three vectors points to a point inside the common intersection of the projections (because the latter is convex). Thus, it determines a line that intersects all three spheres.

Observe that there are many other somewhat more special cases, where the spheres might be in a different positions, so you have to cover them as well. I will have to check the rough code below for errors (another time).

```py
import numpy as np
import math

# I assume your point of view is the origin of the coordinate system, if not, 
# you have to perform a translation from whatever system your coordinates are 
# in to the point of view coordinate system
# 
# the 3 spheres defined by a center and a radius are
P1, r1
P2, r2
P3, r3

def area_Heron(a,b,c):
   p = (a + b + c)/2
   return math.sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c))

def line_through_sphere(V, P, r):
    return (r**2 - np.dot(P,P)) * np.dot(V,V) + (np.dot(P,V))**2 > 0 

def common_tangent(P1, r1, P2, r2, P3, r3):
   l1 = math.sqrt(np.dot(P1, P1))
   l2 = math.sqrt(np.dot(P2, P2))
   d1 = math.sqrt(l1**2 - r1**2)
   d2 = math.sqrt(l2**2 - r2**2)
   a1 = l1 / d1
   a2 = l2 / d2
   b1 = r1 / d1
   b2 = r2 / d2
   A1 = a1 * P1 / l1
   A2 = a2 * P2 / l2
   c = math.sqrt(np.dot(A2-A1, A2-A1))
   hc = 2 * area_Heron(a1, a2, c) / c
   c1 = math.sqrt(a1**2 - hc**2)
   c2 = math.sqrt(a2**2 - hc**2)   
   if c < c1:
       H = (- c2 * A1 + c1 * A2) / c
   elif c < c2:
       H = ( c2 * A1 - c1 * A2) / c
   else
       H = (c2 * A1 + c1 * A2) / c
   h = math.sqrt(hc**2 - 1) * hc
   B = cross(P1, P2)
   B = B / math.sqrt(np.dot(B, B))
   T1 = H + h * B
   T2 = H - h * B
   if line_through_sphere(T1, P3, r3):
      return T1 / math.sqrt(np.dot(T1,T1))
   if line_through_sphere(T2, P3, r3):
      return T2 / math.sqrt(np.dot(T2,T2))

Q1 = common_tangent(P2, r2, P3, r3, P1, r1)
Q2 = common_tangent(P3, r3, P1, r1, P2, r2)
Q3 = common_tangent(P1, r1, P2, r2, P3, r3)

Vector = (Q1 + Q2 + Q3) / 3
```